# Find volume of mic input using minim lib in Processing

Tags: processing, minim

I'm trying to get the volume level from my mic to adjust the size of a box (louder = bigger). But I have the following issues: 
a) getGain seems to be giving me -64 constantly 
b) getVolume doesnt seem to be available

I edited a Processing example to respond to the mic rather than the audio file provided but could not figure out how to get the volume

Here is what I have

```
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim       minim;
AudioInput  accessMic;
FFT         fft;
float boxSize;

void setup () {
  size(512, 200, P3D);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  accessMic = minim.getLineIn();
  rectMode(CENTER);

}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  boxSize = accessMic.getGain();
  stroke(255);
  println(boxSize);
  fill(0);
  rect(width/2,height/2,boxSize,boxSize);
}
```

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with `.getGain();` in minim
I got around to something similar by using `left.level();` which returns float between `0` and `1`. And obviously that only take into account one of the stereo input, you can totally also do `.right.level();` for result from another channel there.

so your code could lookin kinda like
`boxSize = accessMic.left.level() * 100;`
and you'll get box with a size bouncing between 0 and 100!

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [the sound library in Processing](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/Amplitude.html)?

[Here is an example](http://learningprocessing.com/examples/chp20/example-20-09-mic-input).

In minim, you have to use the [`AudioBuffer`](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/audiobuffer_method_level.html) which is exactly what `in.left()` and `in.right()` are. This should give you the same results as the `Amplitude()` function.